# Socket.io, Rest API, problem send message to room

Tags: node.js, angular, express, socket.io

I create a chat in my project so I use socket.io.

Actually, everybody can see a message writed by someone except.... the sender. I don't understand why it doesn't work.

Edit: it worked before I use module.exports.respond, but I need it to use socket.io in my controller.

Here is the code in my chat.service.ts in my front:

```
 public sendMessage(data){
    this.socket.emit('new-message', data);
  }

public newMessageReceived(){
let observable = new Observable<{user:String, message:String}>(observer=>{
  this.socket.on('new-message', (data)=>{
    observer.next(data);
  });
  console.log("échec");
  return () => {this.socket.disconnect();}
});
```

and in my chat.controller:

```
module.exports.respond = (socket: any) => {
    socket.on('join', (data: any) => {
      socket.join(data.room)
      console.log(data.user + 'joined the room : ' + data.room);

      socket.broadcast.to(data.room).emit('new user joined', {user:data.user, message:'has joined this room.'});
    });

    socket.on('leave', (data: any) => {

      console.log(data.user + 'left the room : ' + data.room);

      socket.broadcast.to(data.room).emit('left room', {user:data.user, message:'has left this room.'});

      socket.leave(data.room);
    });


  socket.on('new-message',(data: any) => {
    console.log("Hello", data.room, data.user, data.message)
    socket.in(data.room).emit('new-message', {user:data.user, message:data.message});
  })
}
```

Comment: Use `io.to(data.room).emit(...)` according to the docs socket.to sends the message to everyone but the sender

Comment: Sorry, yes sorry but I tried io.in(data.room).emit(...) which is the good way, and it doesn't work too. I will add some comment in the post.